# Deque push_front() and push_back() without including <deque>

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, stack, deque

I need to create a deque by myself to understand how it works with practice and also I don't need to use the  library, I'd like to write my own functions

I created a class Deque, which has methods push_back(), push_front(), pop_back(), pop_front();

At first I wrote such a code for push_front():

```
void Deque :: push_front( int data, int number ) {

 deque[head - 1] = data;
 head++;
}
```

here is the constructor:

```
  Deque :: Deque( int number ) : head (1), tail (1), 
                                 go_straight (0), go_back (1), 
                                 deque (new int [number]) {
                                    for( int i = 0; i < number; ++i) {
                                       deque[i] = 0;
                                    }
                                 };
```

but this push_front works in such a way:
if I input 4(number of elements) and then 40(value)

```
   40 0 0 0
```

if I input 50(value) it will turn into:

```
  40 50 0 0
```

But I need to do it like this

```
  50 40 0 0
```

In other words I need to move the elements on +1, how can I do that?

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: if you're doing this with an fixed array and don't want to move elements around you have little choice but to do it with a circular buffer, and I'll warn you right now the algorithms are both tedious and involved (i.e. you'll be spending a fair amount of time doing modulo arithmetic and will at some point come to the conclusion that having one "dead" element in the deque solves a number of issues).

Comment: @WhozCraig, couldn't you just help me to move the elements on +1 position? and if it == number - 1 just return 0...I only need the loop to move it on +1. Thanks for your answer

Comment: What part of starting at the opposite end of your sequence and bumping all elements forward by one, leaving a hole at slot `[0]` is causing you trouble?

Comment: @WhozCraig, the part of NOT starting the elements from the opposite side of the array, for example this function                          void Reverse(int *begin, int *end)
{ 
        int temp;
        while (end>begin)
        {
                temp = *begin;
                *begin = *end;
                *end = temp;
                begin++; end--;
        }
}                                                                              Reverse(&deque[0], &deque[i-1]);
     Reverse(&deque[i], &deque[number-1]);
     Reverse(&deque[0], &deque[number-1]);

Comment: @WhozCraig, this function turns the elements on the opposite side, but I need to make it like in the last example

Comment: Why would you reverse *anything*?? The point is to make a **hole** that is filled with the inbound entity..... hang on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your sequence is stored in some array `ar[N]`, and some `ar[len]` where `len < N`is the current "back" of your queue, simply "shift" the elements:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, size_t N>
bool push_front(const T& val, T(&ar)[N], size_t& len)
{
    if (len >= N)
        return false;

    size_t i = len;
    while (i--)
        ar[i+1] = ar[i];
    ar[0] = val;
    ++len;
    return true;
}

template<typename T, size_t N>
void print_array(const T(&ar)[N])
{
    for (auto& x : ar)
        std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    int ar[10] = {0};
    size_t len = 0;
    print_array(ar);

    for (int i=10; push_front(i, ar, len); i+=10);
    print_array(ar);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
100 90 80 70 60 50 40 30 20 10
```

Note: this has O(N) complexity for every insertion (which means O(N^2) for inserting N items). Using a circular buffer and *very* careful modulo arithmetic you can make it O(1), but it isn't trivial, so I warn you ahead of time.

---

Regarding how this *may* work in your code, including fleshing out a copy/swap idiom for compliance with the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29). The two pushes have been implemented. I leave the two pops, the `top()`, and `back()` implementation to you.

```
#include <algorithm>

class Deque
{

private:
    unsigned int size;
    unsigned int length;
    int *elems;

    void swap(Deque& other)
    {
        std::swap(size, other.size);
        std::swap(length, other.length);
        std::swap(elems, other.elems);
    }

public:
    Deque(unsigned int size)
        : size(size)
        , length(0)
        , elems(new int[size]())
    {
    }

    Deque(const Deque& arg)
        : size(arg.size)
        , length(arg.length)
        , elems(new int[arg.size])
    {
        std::copy(arg.elems, arg.elems + arg.length, elems);
    }

    ~Deque()
    {
        delete [] elems;
    }

    Deque& operator =(Deque obj)
    {
        swap(obj);
        return *this;
    }

    // push to the front of the deque
    bool push_front(int value)
    {
        if (length == size)
            return false;

        unsigned int i=length;
        while (i--)
            elems[i+1] = elems[i];
        elems[0] = value;
        ++length;
        return true;
    }

    // push to the back of the deque
    bool push_back(int value)
    {
        if (length == size)
            return false;

        elems[length++] = value;
        return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: excuse me, but how can I do that without the templates?

Comment: @user3347734 just lose the template and either passed the upper bound as another parameter or declare it as a global macro. Either way works.

Comment: for example if I use my constructor and initialize head(0)...then I use your function : void Deque :: push_front(int data, int number)
{

    size_t i = number;
    while (i--)
        deque[i+1] = deque[i];
    deque[0] = data;
    ++number;

} But that doesn't work((

Comment: couldn't you rewrite the code, I have overgoogled everythere and I haven't found anything about deque, because everythere people use <deque>.... Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user3347734 Your class member shouldn't be passing two parameters. Nor, if you're using a shift-design, should you even need two index members (`head` and `tail`). You should only need one: a `length`. Of course you still need a `size` (the max size of the vector). Pushes on the tail side, assuming there is space, simply put the new data at `[length]` and increment `length` afterward. You already know how a head-push works. You code looks like you *started* to do a modulo-based circular buffer, but then opted for a shift-pattern instead.

Comment: @user3347734 ... so rewriting your code isn't really feasible, since its very design is questionable. You seemed to want to know how a shift-right algorithm works to make room for a head-push, thus my answer. If you rework your code to use just a `length` member and top-end `size`, the posted algorithm should dove-tail with that. If not, I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: your code works great, but I need to do that without template, because I haven't begun reading about them yet. I will really appreciate your answer!

Comment: @user3347734 oks. updated. thats about all I can do. gotta get ready for work. best of luck.

Comment: You are very kind, thank you! Good luck! I even can't imagine how to thank you!